# How do I interact with this Maven Archetype properly?

Tags: java, maven, alfresco, maven-archetype

I'm trying to follow the instructions located [here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Benchmark_Framework_2.0:_Developing_Tests) for setting up a sample integration test for Alfresco Benchmark. I'm doing things a little different from the instructions there because when I run this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml
```

I wind up getting this error:

```
Error reading archetype catalog http://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml
...
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: artifacts.alfresco.com
```

So I downloaded the archetype-catalog.xml file and am instead running this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=archetype-catalog.xml
```

This seams to work. Maven does it's Maven stuff and then gets to the same prompt in the instructions I'm following:

```
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 16:
```

to which, per the instructions, I reply:

```
org.alfresco:alfresco-benchmark-sample-archetype
```

This is where things go wrong. Instead of proceding on with the rest of the prompts document in the instructions Maven says:

```
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 16: org.alfresco:alfresco-benchmark-sample-archetype
Choose archetype:
   Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to initial list)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :
```

Questions 
 - What am I doing wrong here? 
 - Has downloading the .xml file manually and then handing it off to Maven caused problems? 
 - Also, in the instructions the prompt has the 475 in it whereas in my version it has the number 16 in it. What is the significance of this number? Why is it different in the prompt I get?

Comment: I supose you are behind a proxy where you gone an round via downloading manually via your browser...

Comment: `artifacts.alfresco.com` exists for me - are you sure you don't have a broken networking setup that's getting in the way?

Comment: @khmarbaise and Gagravarr, yep that's caused by a network config issue. I probably could have dealt with that, but since it's sort of a secondary issue I didn't feel like waiting time on it.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a single number, you make a selection.

When you enter an artifact name, you only apply a filter to the artifact list; after this you still have to select an option (number) from the filtered list.